# I want to get the last letter in a string and print true or false depending on the letter

Tags: java

I am new to programming, currently my first year in trying this. 
Just like the title, i am having a hard time completing this code of mine. 
I already searched high and low and couldn't find something.

The code is incomplete and I know i need to change some things.
What can i do to complete this? I am already worn down.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Ihateyou {
    public static void main (String []args) {
        Scanner fkc = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter an Element or something: ");
            char ch=fkc.next( ).charAt(0);
            String unknown = fkc.nextLine();
            if (ch=='H' + unknown.substring(unknown.length() - 1))
            {
                System.out.println("False  "+ch+" ends with h");
            }
            else if ((ch>='a'&&ch<='z')||(ch>='A'&&ch<='Z'))
                System.out.println("True "+ch+" ends with no H");


    }
}
```

Comment: Its isn't clear what you're trying to do. Could you add a sample input with the expected output?

Comment: Don't get too stressed boss. Its hard as heck to get used to how this all works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        Scanner fkc = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an Element or something: ");

        String unknown = fkc.nextLine();

        char [] arr = unknown.toCharArray();

        int lastLetterIndex = arr.length - 1;

        if(arr[lastLetterIndex]=='h') {

            System.out.println("ends with H");
        }

        else {

            System.out.println("ends with no H");
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It worked. I am really really grateful.

Comment: `str.toCharArray()` creates new array. And you get only one last letter!

Comment: @JackySuit Glad to help Jacky :)

Answer (score 0):

It's nore pretty clear what you want to do, but last letter of the string you can get with `str.charAt(str.length() - 1)`:

```
try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    System.out.print("Enter an Element or something: ");
    String str = scan.nextLine();
    char lastChar = str.charAt(str.length() - 1);

    if (lastChar != 'h')
        System.out.println("False " + str + " ends with h");
    else if (Character.isLetter(lastChar))
        System.out.println("True " + str + " ends with no H");
}
```

Comment: So that's what you use. Thank you, i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you want to do, but I've tried to go thru what your code seems to be doing since you seem a little bit unsure of that, and then propose how I would solve the problem I think you have.

```
public class Ihateyou {
    public static void main (String []args) {
        Scanner fkc = new Scanner (System.in); // This creates a new scanner, which lets us read from System
            System.out.println("Enter an Element or something: "); 
            char ch=fkc.next( ).charAt(0); // This reads the next sequence terminated by the enter key. Then it stores the single first character of that in a char, ch
            String unknown = fkc.nextLine(); // This basically does the same thing, storing it in unknown
            if (ch=='H' + unknown.substring(unknown.length() - 1)) // This checks if ch equals H + most of the unknown string. This doesn't make sense for two reasons.
                                   // One problem is that 'H' + unknown is a string, not a char: it doesn't make sense to compare a String with a char.
                                   // The other is that unless unknown is an empty string (""), and char is 'H', even if we could compare they wouldn't be the same
            {
                System.out.println("False  "+ch+" ends with h");
            }
            else if ((ch>='a'&&ch<='z')||(ch>='A'&&ch<='Z'))
                System.out.println("True "+ch+" ends with no H");


    }
}
```

What I think you might be trying to do is to determine whether the thing the user inputs ends with an H. To do this, I would try the following:

```
public static void main (String []args) {
    Scanner fkc = new Scanner (System.in); // This creates a new scanner, which lets us read from System
        System.out.println("Enter an Element or something: "); 
    String userInput = fkc.nextString(); // Store the next String the user inputs in userInput
    if(userInput.charAt(userInput.length() - 1)) == 'H'){  // userInput.charAt() gets us the character at a given index in the string. We want the last one, so we get 
                               // the one at userInput.length() - 1. Then we check to see if it is H
    {
            System.out.println("False  "+ch+" ends with h");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("True "+ch+" ends with no H");
     }



}
```

Comment: Ahhhhh, i get it now. So you can't compare a char and a string. I didnt know that. 
Thank you for this detailed explanation, you really saved me.